# Change Form Instance Django before Save

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to change a form's instance before I save it. I need to set certain information within the view like this:

```
 class UploadedFile(models.Model):

     file = models.FileField(storage=s3store, upload_to=custom_upload_to)
     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, blank=True)
     bucket = models.ForeignKey(S3Bucket, blank=False)
     uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='uploaded_by', blank=False)
     company = models.ForeignKey(Company, blank=False)
```

--

```
class UploadForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UploadedFile
```

--

```
form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
form.instance.company_id = r_user.company.id
form.instance.uploaded_by_id = r_user.id
form.instance.bucket_id = r_user.company.s3_bucket_id
if form.is_valid():
     form_object = form.save()
```

Now, I get that the form is not valid because company/uploaded/bucket are empty:

Errors Form:

company

This field is required.

bucket

This field is required.

uploaded_by

This field is required.

But I did set them! Do I need to make them blank=True, then do a save(commit=false), change them, and then resave? If yes, why is so? I did change the form ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignments are late. In the `__init__()` of `ModelForm`, or in your code: the `form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)` line, [an instance has been created and populated to `initial` of the form](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L246). Later modification upon the instance will not affect the value of `form.initial`.

Also, if you want to fill in some fields automatically in backend, don't render them to user.

Thus, yes, you could make them `blank=True` or [exclude them from the form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form) then follow [the suggested way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
data = request.POST.copy()
data['company_id'] = r_user.company.id
data['uploaded_by_id'] = r_user.id
data['bucket_id'] = r_user.company.s3_bucket_id

form = UploadForm(data, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
     form_object = form.save()
```

This way you are setting the data before creating the form.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do here a couple of strange things.

First:
Why do you assign to `company_id`, `uploaded_by_id` and `bucket_id`? However yout got those fields in your model - it's names of columns in table created for this model - you should use ORM features directly here e.g. `form.instance.company = r_user.company`.

Second:
Form validation is applied to form.fields not to it's instance attribute, and you can't change them once form is created and bounded to supplied values.

The recommended way to add some fields values to model instance created by form in Django (as I always thought) is to create custom ModelForm as you do and in `Meta` class specify all fields you want allow user to edit. For your case:

```
class UploadForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UploadedFile
        fields = ('file', 'slug')
```

Then instead of calling `form_object = form.save()` you call `form_object = form.save(commit=False)`. Now you got your model instance with all fields from form filled already so you can add what you wish: e.g. `form_object.company = r_user.company`. Finally don't forget to call `save()` on model instance itself to store it in your database.

This solution it described in Django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use)